# Can I check is hardware alright using VM?

Tags: linux, windows-10, wireless-networking, virtual-machine

I use Linux and I have a problem with Wi-Fi. Specifically, signal is extremely weak and sometimes even disconnects.

I tried using the older versions of Ubuntu which I used to use and on which I know that Wi-Fi worked. I also tried downgrading the kernel and the firmware to older versions for the same reason. Wi-Fi worked (or didn't, in this case) the same way so I concluded that it is the hardware that is broken.

As the last test, I want to try Windows 10. As I cannot just boot Windows 10 in live mode to check the Wi-Fi, and I don't want to destroy my current setup, can I use VM instead? Specifically, will Windows 10 run its drivers on bare metal, or through some wrapper which may change the way Windows 10 handles wireless connection?

If the answer is "no", is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtual Win10 would use the host Linux Wifi, so I guess you cannot make Win10 use more signal strength. I advise to ask a Linux forum like askubuntu.com

Comment: Btw, can I generate ISO from my current system and then install Windows 10 and after that retrieve my current system using the created ISO?

Comment: You could make by full backup of your system using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonezilla (or simular) and later copy it back to the system